# LINUX FIFO named pipe (IPC) joined adjacent messages together

Tags: linux, pipe, ipc

I'm communicating between two non-related process (not folked from the same parent) using Named Pipe (fifo mode).
The program works. However, at some point, at very little delay time between messages, adjacent received messages at the pipe reader is combined (joined)

In the code below, I would like to see the output of the "reader" as:

```
Received buffer: 1000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 2000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 1000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 2000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 1000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 2000 (bytes)
....
Received buffer: 1000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 2000 (bytes)

But the actual output is:
Received buffer: 1000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 2000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 1000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 2000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 3000 (bytes)           <-- This is the problem. Two message are combined at the reader. It actuall: 1000 + 2000 = 3000 bytes
....
Received buffer: 1000 (bytes)
Received buffer: 2000 (bytes)
```

At the "write" side, I use `usleep(5000)` to set a small delay between each message. If i increase the time, for example `usleep(50000)`, the result is CORRECT as expected.
So the cause is too small delay time. But my program needs that small delay.

But the way the pipe works here is very confused. Why it combines message? Could you explain for me? Thanks you so much!

Here is my code: The writer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit functions */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, pipe, _exit */
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char msg1[] = "long message 1";     // The message length is 1000 bytes
    char msg2[] = "long message 2";     // The message length is 2000 bytes

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        return;
    }

    while(1) {
        write(fd, msg1, sizeof(msg1));
        usleep(5000);   // 5 ms

        write(fd, msg2, sizeof(msg2));
        usleep(5000);   // 5 ms
    }
    close(fd);

    /* remove the FIFO */
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

The reader:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 500

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);

    while(1) {
        if (read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0) {
            printf("Received buffer: %d (bytes)\n", sizeof(buf));
        }
    }
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe `The communication channel provided by a pipe is a byte stream: there is no concept of message boundaries. ` So, this behavior is expected, you need to handle pipes as any stream-based connection, such as TCP.

Comment: If you want a message-oriented approach, use a datagram or seqpacket unix domain socket instead.

Comment: You also need to capture `read()`'s return value any method you use so you know how many bytes were actually read.

Comment: (also your reader program will never produce the output you say it does...)

Comment: Thanks guys, I know what to do know: The writer must write info about message length, the the reader check this length to parse correct number of bytes (depending on the message)